# SQL: Same date but different values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that looks like this

| Station | year | month | day | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1990 | 1 | 1 | 50 |
| A1 | 1990 | 1 | 1 | 60 |
| A1 | 1990 | 1 | 2 | 55 |
| A1 | 1990 | 1 | 3 | 10 |
| A1 | 1990 | 1 | 4 | 40 |

In example , the query result will like below table

for same station and date

| Station | year | month | day | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1990 | 1 | 1 | 50 |
| A1 | 1990 | 1 | 1 | 60 |

How to set a proper SQL for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want rows where the first four columns are duplicated.  A simple method uses `count(*)`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by station, year, month, date) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: This answer is not matching the requirement mentioned in the question title -- "SQL: Same date but different values"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table have a primary key column called `id`, we can also try using exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.Station = t1.Station AND t2.year = t1.year AND
                    t2.month = t1.month AND t2.day = t1.day AND t2.id <> t1.id);
```

If you don't have such an `id` column, then we could also use aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Station, year, month, day
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Station, year, month, day
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t2.Station = t1.Station AND t2.year = t1.year AND t2.month = t1.month AND
       t2.day = t1.day;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` clause to find exact duplicate with different number as follows:

```
Select t.*
  From your_table t
 Where exists
   (select 1 from your_table tt
     Where tt.station = t.station
       And tt.year = t.year
       And tt.month = t.month
       And tt.date = t.date
       And tt.number <> t.number)
```